# Installing R Package from GitHub without Admin Privileges (e.g. locally)

Tags: r, github, install.packages

I am trying to install BASiCS (an R Package): https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BASiCS/versions/0.3.1

I don't have Admin privileges.

I've tried the following commands:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("catavallejos/BASiCS", lib="/mnt/data1/local/Rpackages")
```

But it's not working because I don't have admin privileges:

```
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/mnt/data1/bin/R/site-packages’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

How do I install BASiCS without having admin privileges?

Comment: Set `.libPaths()` to a directory to which you have write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install R in your own user directory. I have the same issue.